# Index out of range when removing value from array

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm adding values to an array when a user clicks a cell like so:

```
var savedArray = [] as Array
self.savedArray.append(obj[indexPath.row].title as Any)
```

This is successfully saving the values. But, when I want to remove them (when they deselect the cell) it says 'Fatal Index out of range'.

```
let number = indexPath.row       
self.savedArray.remove(at: number)
```

Oddly enough, this code works for the first (0) indexPath, but not the others. Is there a fix? Thank you.

Comment: The value of ```number``` variable is verly likely going beyond the borders of your array... Have you tried printing it ?

Comment: You are using an index of a different collection. Why would you expect both elements to be in the same index?

Comment: First change the declaration of your savedArray. Don't use `Any`. Use the type of your element. Make your `Element` (probably a String) and conform to `Equatable` (if it doesn't String does conform to Equatable). Then find the firstIndex of your element in your savedArray and remove it.

Comment: @cocool97 Yes, when I print it it does successfully show the IndexPath.

Comment: @LeoDabus if I do that it just says Protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an index of a different collection. Why would you expect both elements to be in the same index? What happens is that the two collection have different number of elements. First change the declaration of your savedArray. Don't use `Any`. Use the type of your element. Make your array type the same type as your title property. Then find the firstIndex of your element in your `savedArray` and remove it.

Your code should look something like this (if your title property is a String):

Array declaration:

```
var savedArray: [String] = []
```

Appending new elements:

```
self.savedArray.append(obj[indexPath.row].title)
```

Removing the element:

```
if let index = self.savedArray.firstIndex(of: obj[indexPath.row].title) {
    self.savedArray.remove(at: index)
}
```